# Las o los VTC digitales

Tags: gramática

Quisiera confirmar si se debe usar el artículo femenino o masculino en "[mientras 'las' o 'los' VTC digitales tienen todas un servicio prepago y precios que se calculan antes de contratarse, los taxis suelen funcionar por lo general con una tarifa y no se paga hasta el final.](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.xataka.com/basics/que-significa-vtc-cuales-diferencias-taxis/amp)" ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Qué significa VTC?

Comment: Los vehiculos no las.

Comment: ¿La pregunta es por cuál el artículo correcto para VTC? Por favor, aclará mejor la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> VTC son las siglas con las que se conoce al término **vehículo de transporte con conductor**, que es como se le llama a los vehículos con chófer que trasladan a uno o varios pasajeros desde un lugar de origen a otro de destino.

De acá queda claro que el núcleo del sujeto al que el término refiere es *vehículo*, un sustantivo de género masculino. Luego, al emplear el término, sea en forma completa o abreviada, deberá usarse **el** o **los** dependiendo si es singular o plural.

Por lo tanto, en el párrafo:

> Aunque todos son servicios de vehículos con chófer, existen algunas diferencias marcan una línea entre los taxis y los VTC como Uber o Cabify. La primera está en el modo en el que se contratan ambos servicios, ya que mientras **las** VTC digitales tienen todas un servicio prepago y precios que se calculan antes de contratarse, los taxis suelen funcionar por lo general con una tarifa y no se paga hasta el final.

se equivocó el autor, lo correcto es **los** VTC.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por su respuesta, tac!